# Android Status bar overlapping on my screen

Tags: android-support-library, android-appcompat, react-native, stack-navigator

There are some topics that I came by discussing the same issue but they were platform specific. For example, for `iOS` it was suggested to add padding to the top of the screen component or add an empty view with a height equals that padding. So what happens is that we do a simple check on the platform used, if it is `iOS` apply the padding or the empty view otherwise nothing.

The approach has been working like a charm for me but not until I encountered some Android devices face the same issue so the padding and the empty view options are off the table now because it is not platform specific any longer, means if I apply the padding in this case, the other sound Android devices' screens will be unnecessarily pushed down *which is going to result in a bad UI experience.*

**This is what I have implemented in my app:**

```
export default () =>
  <Root>
    <View
      style={{
        height: Platform.OS === "ios" ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0,
        backgroundColor: "transparent"
      }}/>
    <App />
  </Root>;
```

Where App is a `Stack Navigator` and StatusBar is `RN status bar API` (see [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar.html#barstyle))